# Unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end error in controller on object creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

In my Rails application I have an association between `experience` and `company` and I want to set all companies created through experiences to be not public visible.

For that I have this code in my `experience` model:

```
  def company_name=(name)
    company = Company.find_or_initialize_by(name: name)

    if company.new_record?
      public_visibility: false
    end
  end
```

but this doesn't work and raises following error:

> unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end public_visibility: false

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: I'm getting this error   syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end public_visibility: false ^

Comment: Not sure hwat is expected, but you have syntax error. Do you mean `company.public_visibility = false` instead of `public_visibility: false`?

Comment: can you teach me? ;) so what are you thinking

Comment: and if there is something that i have never meet what can i do? I think this is why this website was created for, but person like you think that everyone must be an expert

Comment: by do way you can down vote my question as much as you can

Comment: Thank you very much without you i can't achieve this, but i just defensed myself it is all

Comment: sorry for my offense, and think you for your help i'm just trying to learn and my language doesn't help me very much, that is all, sorry another time

Comment: @djrs12 no problem, see my edit as an example how to ask properly: be specific, show error and relevant code parts - this way you'll receive answers faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like that:-

```
def company_name=(name)
  company = Company.find_or_initialize_by(name: name)
  if company.new_record?
    company.public_visibility = false
    company.save
  end
end
```